# Hide the TabControl header

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, tabcontrol

What's the programmatic way (ie not using styles as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387480/hide-tab-headers-in-wpf-tabcontrol), but using code) to hide the `TabControl` header? I'll be glad for a snippet.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
Style s = new Style();
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed));
tabControl.ItemContainerStyle = s;
```

Answer (score 91):

Actually, it's very straight forward to hide the tab strip.  You just set each `TabItem`s `Visibility` to `Collapsed`.  You still see the tab content,...just not the tab header itself.

Comment: Mine too, Do you know why it has this behavior? We were expecting the tab container to disappear completely.

Comment: This worked for me, too - thanks. I also ended up creating a BooleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter so that I could data-bind this property to my view-model.

Comment: This only shows the tab content from the first tab for me. That happens to be what I want, but this odd behavior makes me reluctant to use it in production. Does anyone have an explanation why this works?

Comment: This works, but when you try to edit the content inside the TabItem, it won't work. So I find my self removing Visibility="Collapsed", editing the child items, then putting Visibility="Collapsed" back onto the element. Kind of annoying.

Comment: @edwardm thanks for mentioning! this will prevent a lot of bugs and googling :p. But how to toggle the tabitem visibilty property in codebehind?

Comment: You can also set the height to 0. I prefer this in some cases depending how I want things to display. Also I like to bind the property so I can swap between tabs with ease.

Comment: Great, and in Sebastian's answer this gets even better.

Answer (score 22):

Simple XAML Style

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Better solution than the upper one when you have a lot of tabs

Answer (score 9):

Well, there are several ways to do this.

The ugliest way: Use VisualTreeHelper to find TabPanel (or any other Panel you use to host items), and set it's Visibility property to Visibility.Collapsed. Why ugly? It's easy to create few annoying bugs here or break this approach with 'harmless' style update if you was not careful enough...

I prefer using combination of Xaml and code behind. You bind either TabItem's visibility to view model property or TabPanel's visibility to view model property. In both cases you have to override style (either ItemContainer's style or whole TabControl's style). In both cases you have view model. Now, to toggle tab header's visibility, you just update a property in the view model. Here is an example with TabItems:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="Tab Settings"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:TabControlViewModel x:Key="tabVM" />
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <TabControl DataContext="{StaticResource tabVM}">
      <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
          <Setter Property="Visibility"
                  Value="{Binding TabHeaderVisible, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </Style>
      </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="Content" />
          <Button Content="Toggle Header"
                  Click="ToggleHeaderClick" />
        </StackPanel>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="Tab 2 Header">
        <TextBlock Text="Tab 2 Content" />
      </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public Window1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ToggleHeaderClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var tabControlVM =
        ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as TabControlViewModel;
      if (tabControlVM != null)
      {
        tabControlVM.TabHeaderVisible = !tabControlVM.TabHeaderVisible;
      }
    }
  }

  public class TabControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private bool _tabHeaderVisible = true;

    public ICommand ToggleHeader
    {
      get; private set;
    }

    public bool TabHeaderVisible
    {
      get { return _tabHeaderVisible; }
      set
      {
        _tabHeaderVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TabHeaderVisible");
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
      var changed = PropertyChanged;
      if (changed != null)
      {
        changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I was expecting a line such as `tab.Header.Visible = false` not to a gigantic XML+code behind monster!

Comment: This shows the appropriate way to accomplish this within the MVVM design pattern. While this is not what the question asked for, it is still helpful for those enforcing the pattern throughout their code.

Comment: useful if you are stritcly MVVM, but in some projects which necessarily use database generated things like a POS, this is not realistic to enforce, especially because there is litle to no XAML. However, any tips for projects like that to keep the code cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this in some code where I populate the tab items manually...

```
tabItemToAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

...but then I had a weird thing happen where the second time I'd clear out the tab control's items, create the tab item again and use this approach before adding it to the tab control, the entire tab item and its contents were gone, not just the tab header.  So I've had success with the programmatic equivalent of [this solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f500ff28-83e7-439a-ad78-be0e6a3b7587/how-to-hide-the-tab-headers-for-a-tabcontrol?forum=wpf):

```
tabItemToAdd.Template = new ControlTemplate();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use C# and set the x:Name for the TabItem, you can also manipulate the Visibility like so:

```
tabItemName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private void TabItemControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.TabItemControl.IsSelected == false)
    {
        this.TabItemControl.Opacity = 100;
    }
}

private void TabItemControl_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.TabItemControl.IsSelected == false)
    {
        this.TabItemControl.Opacity = 0;
    }
}

private void TabAllControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.TabItemControl.IsSelected == false)
    {
        this.TabItemControl.Opacity = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give some background as to why this is the answer

Comment: Please only answer if you understand the question.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.